# Usar resultados de una consulta para utilizarlos en otra consulta SQL

Tags: sql, vbscript

Buen día.

Les explico...

Tengo una primer consulta que me regresa 13 registros FechaInicio y FechaFinal

Primer consulta:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 13
        Fecha,
        FecPag
    FROM
        Nonom
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada Rango de fechas es una semana, estos rangos los voy a utilizar en otra consulta para obtener el total a pagar de cada empleado durante esas semanas.

Ejemplo 2da consulta:

```sql
SELECT 
   IdEmpleado, Nombre, Pago
FROM
   Empleado E, Liquida L
WHERE
   E.IdEmpleado = L.IdEmpleado AND
   L.Fecha BETWEEN "FechaInicio" AND "FechaFinal"
```

Estaba pensando algo así ,pero no sé como tomar los datos de la primer consulta.

Comment: Agrega el código VB. También puede quedar en una sola consulta, agrega el SQL de la primer consulta.

Comment: Para poder responderte, incluye el código de la primera consulta.

Comment: Lo que vos queres no son unas consultas.. es todo un proceso...

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener solo las liquidaciones que caigan en esas 13 semanas podrías vincular (INNER JOIN) en la segunda consulta con una subconsulta que sería tu primer consulta.

Para SqlServer:

```
SELECT E.IdEmpleado, E.Nombre, L.Pago
FROM Empleado E 
INNER JOIN Liquida L ON E.IdEmpleado = L.IdEmpleado
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 13 CONVERT(date, Fecha) AS FechaInicio, CONVERT(date, FecPag) AS FechaFinal 
            FROM Nonom
            ORDER BY Fecha DESC) AS fecha ON L.Fecha BETWEEN fecha.FechaInicio AND fecha.FechaFinal;
```

Si quisieras totalizar los pagos (por empleado, o por empleado y semana) deberías utilizar la cláusula `GROUP BY` y la función `SUM()`.

Para obtener el total a pagar por semana y por empleado deberías agrupar por E.IdEmpleado, E.Nombre, fecha.FechaInicio y sumar los pagos (L.Pago):

```
SELECT E.IdEmpleado, E.Nombre, fecha.FechaInicio, SUM(L.Pago) AS total
FROM Empleado E 
INNER JOIN Liquida L ON E.IdEmpleado = L.IdEmpleado
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 13 CONVERT(date, Fecha) AS FechaInicio, CONVERT(date, FecPag) AS FechaFinal 
            FROM Nonom) AS fecha ON L.Fecha BETWEEN fecha.FechaInicio AND fecha.FechaFinal
GROUP BY E.IdEmpleado, E.Nombre, fecha.FechaInicio;
```

Comment: Realice la consulta pero me duplica los resultados, exactamente lo que necesito es que me devuelva cada semana con el total a pagar por empleado.

Comment: @AlexisSanchez ¿te duplica todos los renglones o es que un empleado puede tener varias liquidaciones en una misma semana? Suponiendo que mi query sea correcta (porque no conozco bien tu modelo de datos) agregué una segunda query que totaliza el total a pagar por empleado y por semana.